# How do I force floating point values greater than 1e-8 to 0

Tags: c#, precision, gaussian

I'm currently working on implementing Matrix forward reduction, and this far it passes almost all of my test cases. However I have problem rounding floating point values. I reduce non-zero rows below a pivot element by simply adding -1*a[j,col]/a[i,col], where i = pivot, and j is initialized at i + 1, iterating downward until all rows are done.

However say I want a tolerance of 1e-10 for floating point comparisons. How can I force values in a[j,col] to zero if they exceed this tolerance?

In some cases I have values at 1e-14 to 1e-15, in my test cases, which should be zero. The current cases I tried is shown below, but this did not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? '

This is the first time I try comparing floating point values, which I have read can be difficult, so I hope someone can help me solve this, as it is currently forcing my application at a stand still until it is fixed.

```
var tolerance = 1e-10;
if (a[j, lead] < a[j, lead]*tolerance) { 
    a[j, lead] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting 0 everywhere, right?

Comment: Should probably be Math.Abs(a - b) < tolerance.  But you'd be wise to go shopping a bit, some matrix manipulations are especially likely to become numerically unstable.  Like the kind of gaussian elimination you learned in school.  You can easily make that a lot worse by intentionally generating happy numbers.  Give the Math.NET library a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your conditions completely, but if you just care about the exponent you could check what the exponents are and based off of that check if it fits your criteria.

Your title sais "How do I force floating point values greater than 1e-8 to 0":

```
var tolerance = 1e-8;
bool compareExponents = 
(int) Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(a[j, lead]))) > 
(int) Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(tolerance))) ? true : false;

a[j,lead] = compareExponents ? 0 : a[j,lead];
//if the value(i.e a[j,lead]) is larger than the tolerance, i'm setting the value to 0. 
//otherwise, just keep the current value.
//
//1e^-15 > tolerance ==> 0
//1e^-8 > tolerance ==> a[j,lead]
```

If you only care about the exponent not exceeding a specific value, you can try this.

Comment: Sorry for a late answer, but it was exactly was I was looking for thanks :-) and it solved the problem I had!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
var tolerance = 1e-10;
var fraction = a[j, lead] - Math.Truncate(a[j, lead];
if (fraction<tolerance)
{
    a[j, lead] = 0;
}
```